# Is there a way to share swagger annotation for different methods?

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot

I have different RestAPI methods that correspond to endpoints and I would like to share their @ApiResponses to avoid code duplication. I basically have the following annotation to 8 different methods and I would like ideally to define it only once.

```
@ApiResponses(value = {@ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "OK"),
            @ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "Bad Request", response = ResourceErrorModel.class),
            @ApiResponse(code = 401, message = "Unauthorized", response = ResourceErrorModel.class),
            @ApiResponse(code = 403, message = "Forbidden", response = ResourceErrorModel.class),
            @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "Not Found", response = ResourceErrorModel.class),
            @ApiResponse(code = 409, message = "Conflict", response = ResourceErrorModel.class),
            @ApiResponse(code = 422, message = "Unprocessable Entity", response = ResourceErrorModel.class),
            @ApiResponse(code = 424, message = "Failed Dependency", response = ResourceErrorModel.class)})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a custom interface as `CustomAPIResponse` as below:

```
@Target({METHOD, TYPE})
@ApiResponses(value = {
            @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "OK"),
            @ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "Bad Request", response = ResourceErrorModel.class),
            @ApiResponse(code = 401, message = "Unauthorized", response = ResourceErrorModel.class),
            @ApiResponse(code = 403, message = "Forbidden", response = ResourceErrorModel.class),
            @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "Not Found", response = ResourceErrorModel.class),
            @ApiResponse(code = 409, message = "Conflict", response = ResourceErrorModel.class),
            @ApiResponse(code = 422, message = "Unprocessable Entity", response = ResourceErrorModel.class),
            @ApiResponse(code = 424, message = "Failed Dependency", response = ResourceErrorModel.class)})
public @interface CustomAPIResponse{}
```

Then over your each controller method of REST API simply annotate the function with `@CustomAPIResponse`. This will simply add all of the annotations mentioned in `CustomAPIResponse` class.

You can create multiple such type of `@interface` class & also single function can be annotated with multiple custom annotations as created above.

Answer (score 4):

You could try to create your own annotation and add it on your methods:

```java
@Target(value=METHOD)
@Retention(value=RUNTIME)
@ApiResponses(value = {@ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "OK"),
            @ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "Bad Request", response = ResourceErrorModel.class),
            @ApiResponse(code = 401, message = "Unauthorized", response = ResourceErrorModel.class),
            @ApiResponse(code = 403, message = "Forbidden", response = ResourceErrorModel.class),
            @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "Not Found", response = ResourceErrorModel.class),
            @ApiResponse(code = 409, message = "Conflict", response = ResourceErrorModel.class),
            @ApiResponse(code = 422, message = "Unprocessable Entity", response = ResourceErrorModel.class),
            @ApiResponse(code = 424, message = "Failed Dependency", response = ResourceErrorModel.class)})
public @interface SomeCustomAnnotation {}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could create your own annotation, which is annotated with `@ApiResponses`:

```java
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({METHOD, TYPE})
@ApiResponses({
        @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "OK"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "Bad Request", response = ResourceErrorModel.class),
        @ApiResponse(code = 401, message = "Unauthorized", response = ResourceErrorModel.class),
        @ApiResponse(code = 403, message = "Forbidden", response = ResourceErrorModel.class),
        @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "Not Found", response = ResourceErrorModel.class),
        @ApiResponse(code = 409, message = "Conflict", response = ResourceErrorModel.class),
        @ApiResponse(code = 422, message = "Unprocessable Entity", response = ResourceErrorModel.class),
        @ApiResponse(code = 424, message = "Failed Dependency", response = ResourceErrorModel.class)})
public @interface DefaultApiResponses {

}
```

Then simply annotate your controller methods:

```
@GetMapping("/foo")
@DefaultApiResponses
public Response<Foo> getFoo() {
    ...
}
```